# Moving a DOM object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, typeerror

I'm new to javascript, and am just trying to move link whenever it is moused over.

I was hoping the following code would do it. but it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined`.

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
    yPosition = parseInt(Math.random() * window.screen.availHeight);
    xPosition = parseInt(Math.random() * window.screen.availWidth);
    $(this).style.left = xPosition + "px";
    $(this).style.top = yPosition + "px";
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` is a jquery object.. While `style` is native dom property.

Comment: Using jQuery `$(this).style.left= xPosition + "px";` must be `$(this).css('left', xPosition + "px");`

Comment: @choz is right. You need to write selector and get the DOM element. Modify it then.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, pick an answer, please.

Comment: Never. Use. parseInt. With. Numbers.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond to responses earlier, it's been a busy couple of days. I've tried both changing `parseInt` to `Number`, and using `.css()`, without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) . The reason why you had that error is because:

- `.style` is for plain JavaScript inline style properties.
- `$(this)` is a jQuery object thus you should use jQuery methods unless you dereference it: `$(selector)[0]`

Make sure to review Snippet in Full page mode, the links shoot off like scattering cockroaches.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('a').hover(function() {
  var yPosition = parseFloat(Math.random() * window.screen.availHeight)+'px';
  console.log(yPosition);
  var xPosition = parseFloat(Math.random() * window.screen.availWidth)+'px';
  console.log(xPosition);
  $(this).css({
    left: xPosition,
    top: yPosition
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you'll have to replace

```
$(this).style.left = xPosition + "px";
```

by

```
$(this).css('left', xPosition + "px");
```

You can replace both style lines

```
$(this).style.left = xPosition + "px";
$(this).style.top = yPosition + "px";
```

by using this syntax:

```
$(this).css({ left: xPosition, top: yPosition });
```

The unit `px` can be omitted safely using this.

For reference, check the jQuery API:

> http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, and I'm no longer getting an error now, but the `'a'` objects are not moving.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below version. It will work

```
   $('a').mouseover(function(){
    yPosition = parseInt(Math.random() * window.screen.availHeight);
    xPosition = parseInt(Math.random() * window.screen.availWidth);
    $(this).css('left', xPosition + "px");
    $(this).css('top', yPosition + "px");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

the `$(this)` creates a jquery object, and these do not have the `style` property.

Either use the raw DOM properties as you try

```
this.style.left = xPosition + "px";
this.style.top = yPosition + "px";
```

or if you want to use jQuery use `.css` and change both positions in one go

```
$(this).css({
    left: xPosition,
    top: yPosition 
});
```